# Defaulting to different URLs when Generating Web Service Proxy with WSDL.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I have numerous Web Services in my project that share types.

For simplicity I will demonstrate with two Web Services.

WebService1 at http://MyServer/WebService.asmx
webService2 at http://MyServer/WebService.asmx

When I generate the proxy for these two services I use:

wsdl /sharetypes http://MyServer/WebService1.asmx http://MyServer/WebService2.asmx
/appsettingurlkey:WebServiceUrl /namespace:MyNamespace /out:MyProxy.cs

The problem is that the appsettingurlkey is the same for each Web Service
in the proxy file. I want to be able to specify multiple
appsettingurlkey parameters. How is this accomplished? I figure
since the /sharetypes parameter became available, there should be a
solution for specifying the appsettingurlkey specifically for each
Web Service identified.

If this is not possible with the wsdl.exe, what would you propose I do? I would rather not update the generated code that wsdl.exe outputs and I don't want to go through my whole application passing in the Url to each instance of the Web Services.

Comment: It's no answer, so in comment: Why don't you use svcutil.exe to generate a WCF client code instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proxy classes generated are partial classes, so my solution would be to add your own constructor in a different (non-generated) code file, which explicitly reads a different setting for each proxy.

Answer (score 1):

To suplement Elijah's own answer, here's the email answer I gave him.

I had to blog it because the XML didn't paste well into this text box: http://www.rickdoes.net/blog/archive/2008/09/29/wsdl-shared-types-and-configuration.aspx

Comment: Apologies: http://www.rickdoes.net/post/2008/09/29/WSDL-Shared-Types-and-configuration.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, instead of creating another partial class with an overloaded constructor passing in the Url, the following additional parameters to the wsdl.exe will solve my problem...

wsdl /sharetypes http://MyServer/WebService1.asmx http://MyServer/WebService2.asmx /appsettingurlkey:WebServiceUrl /namespace:MyNamespace /out:MyProxy.cs **/appsettingurlkey:BaseSoapUrl /appsettingbaseurl:http://MyServer/**

If the web.config has a BaseSoapUrl appSetting, then it will use that to replace the http://MyServer/ sub string from the MyProxy.cs. If the appSetting is not present, then it will just use the path provided in the wsdl.exe (example: {BaseSoapUrl}/WebService1.asmx when using the appSetting or http://MyServer/WebService1.asmx when not using the appSetting).

A thanks goes out to Rick Kierner for pointing me in the right direction.